# mongoid before_destroy callback on has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a simple has_and_belongs_to_many relation set up in Mongoid like so:

```
class Post

  ...

  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors

  scope :live, lambda{ published.where(:published_at.lt => Time.now) }

end


class Author

  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts

  before_save :count_posts

  def count_posts
    self.post_count = posts.live.length
  end

end
```

When I update the Post model and destroy an Author / Post relationship, how can I do an before_destroy or some other callback on the author to update the post count?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any features built into Mongoid relationships that would help with this, but what you can do is add a before_destroy callback on the post that tells each author it belongs to that it's being deleted by simply triggering a save on that author so that your count_posts hook is called.

```
class Post
    has_and_belongs_to_many :authors

    after_remove :update_author_counts

    scope :live, lambda{ published.where(:published_at.lt => Time.now) }

    ....

    protected

    def update_author_counts
        # Assuming you keep the count_posts callback in
        # your author model, all you have to do is trigger a save
        authors.each { |a| a.save }
    end  

end
```

Reference: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html

Comment: I need it to work when updating a Post, not deleting - is there a similar method I can use to this?

Comment: My apologies I read the question wrong.  Mongoid provides callbacks for association changes as well, I've updated the answer.